# Converting List to a DataTable and/or DataSet Extension Methods

Tags: c#, converting, extension-methods, .net-datatable

Can someone help me improve this code?  I and trying to have a couple extension methods to convert strongly-typed lists to a `DataSet` and `DataTable` respectively.

But... being so green to C#, I am not sure this is the most efficient way to do this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

namespace o7th.Class.Library.Data
{
/// <summary>
/// List to DataTable Converter
/// </summary>
public static class ListConverter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert our List to a DataTable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns>DataTable</returns>
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
        {
            long _pCt = props.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < _pCt; ++i)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                long _vCt = values.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < _vCt; ++i)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert our List to a DataSet
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <returns>DataSet</returns>
    public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Type elementType = typeof(T);
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            using (DataTable t = new DataTable())
            {
                ds.Tables.Add(t);
                //add a column to table for each public property on T
                PropertyInfo[] _props = elementType.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in _props)
                {
                    Type _pi = propInfo.PropertyType;
                    Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(_pi) ?? _pi;
                    t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
                }
                //go through each property on T and add each value to the table
                foreach (T item in list)
                {
                    DataRow row = t.NewRow();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in _props)
                    {
                        row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    t.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the using statement in the ToDataSet function call the Dispose method?

Comment: Yes, however, since we are returning it, it would be pointless to include it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things I notice right off the bat.

1. Your variable names while not bad, could be better.  For instance `props` -> `properties`.  Stuff like this makes the code easier to read.
2. You have the properties, why not use a `foreach` loop to fill the datatable (you did it in ToDataSet)
3. the `_` prefex should be used for class variables, not local variables.
4. try using `var` when declaring obvious variable types `var row = t.NewRow()`
5. There is no error checking when you are filling the values in the data table.  What happens if it is not a class (int, double, long)?  You could force the generic to be a class by adding `where T : class`.
6. Why don't you use the `ToDataTable` method to create the table in the `ToDataSet` method?  This will eliminate duplicate code, and have 1 point of failure/modification as required.  As an aside, I would use the code from `ToDataSet` to create your `DataTable`, as it is written better.
7. While I applaud your use of it, I'm not sure the `using` syntax is appropriate here.  I would move that to where these methods are being called `using (var dt = list.ToDataTable())`  Having it here will more than likely cause unexpected things to happen in your code.
8. I would make these extend `IEnumerable<T>` as that will make them way more useful by not limiting them to `IList<T>`.

I do like your use of white space and indentation, so good job on that.  The extra indentation will be removed when the `using` statements are removed.  I also like the name of your methods, very clear and concise to their intent.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and suggestions.  :)  Couple questions/comments. #5 not worried about that just yet, but it will go in. #4. I've always been under the impression that it is more efficient to properly declare my variables, what would the benefit be of making it a variable type rather than a DataRow?  (updated the q, with new code)

Comment: [var actually is strongly typed in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).  It picks up the type you are assigning it.  I like it because it cleans the code up a little more.

Comment: I never see you in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), even though you are an active user.  You should join us sometime! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using this below code, you can convert `List<YourClassname>` to `DataTable`:-

```
List<YourClass> objlist = alldata;
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objlist);
DataTable dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

Here, I'm assuming that `alldata` contains `list<YourClass>` object and you can also do - `objlist.Add(objYourClass)`. Hope, these codes help you!!!

Comment: Right, but that also assumes I will include Newtonsoft JSON object as a dependancy to all project using this.

No, this is definately not a viable solution to this 5yr old question

Comment: It is working fine for me. I thing you are having trouble to understand my code. Or your working criteria could be differ from me.

Comment: I'm not having trouble understanding your code mate.  You are utilizing a 3rd party reference to do what I have done without.   I won't use Newtonsoft.Json's object to do this